# Is there a limit of how many transactions I can send to neo4j using the Cypher transaction HTTP endpoint?

Tags: neo4j, transactions

I am getting `Unrecognized transaction` erros when I send more than 80something individual calls after starting a transaction.

Is there a limit of how many transactions I can send to neo4j using the Cypher transaction HTTP endpoint? Can I get around this somehow? I cannot switch to bolt (which is fine) unfortunately due to some deployment limitations I am trying to get around with using http.

The issue is not related to exceeding the 60 secs transaction timeout. Could the issue be related to parallel calls to add to an open transaction? If I guarantee that each call is made sequentially it works but it is very slow.

https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/

Comment: There is no limit as far as I know. Can you share a snippet of how you are trying to access the API? However, if the queries you are triggering are not related, it will be better to use a start-and-commit transaction endpoint. https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request/

Comment: I created a test where I added commands to an open transaction one by one and 10k+ calls were accepted. I think the issue is adding to a transaction parallel. One command may still run while the next one added. I will so some more testing. `/db/neo4j/tx/commit` works but each command will run as separated transaction which is not great.

Comment: Yeah, parallelism can definitely cause some issues.